# .htaccess Rewrite Conditions to nginx config - multiple conditions & rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have the following rewrites in .htaccess:

```
#exception for shorthand phpthumb links eg /userfiles/myimage.jpg?w=300
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|JPG|)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/third_party/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../../../$1&%1 [NE,L]
```

It checks that request is for one of the specified (image) files and that has some query string arguments. In that case it should rewrite to an automatic thumbnail script.

I am trying to rewrite that into nginx config. So far I've got this:

```
location \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|JPG)$ {
    if($args ~ "^(.+)$"){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /application/third_party/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../../../$1 last;
    }
}
```

I am new to nginx and tried to glue together the new config from some manuals and this converter:
http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the rewrite with the following:

```
location ~ /(images|userfiles)/ {
    if ($args) {
        # alternative shorthand phpthumb links eg /userfiles/myimage.jpg?w=300
        rewrite .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ /application/third_party/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../../..$uri last;
    }
}
```